# How can I write a lens for a sum type

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a type like this:

```
data Problem =
   ProblemFoo Foo |
   ProblemBar Bar |
   ProblemBaz Baz
```

`Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` all have a lens for their names:

```
fooName :: Lens' Foo String
barName :: Lens' Bar String
bazName :: Lens' Baz String
```

Now I'd like to create a lens

```
problemName :: Lens' Problem String
```

Clearly I can write this using the [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:lens) construction function and a pair of case statements, but is there a better way?

The documentation for [`outside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:outside) talks about using a Prism as a kind of first-class pattern, which sounds suggestive, but I can't see how to actually make it happen.

(Edit: added `Baz` case because my real problem isn't isomorphic with `Either`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right in that you can write it with `outside`. To begin with, some definitions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

newtype Foo = Foo { _fooName :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
makeLenses ''Foo

newtype Bar = Bar { _barName :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
makeLenses ''Bar

newtype Baz = Baz { _bazName :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
makeLenses ''Baz

data Problem =
    ProblemFoo Foo |
    ProblemBar Bar |
    ProblemBaz Baz
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
makePrisms ''Problem
```

The above is just what you described in your question, except that I'm also making prisms for `Problem`.

The type of `outside` (specialised to functions, simple lenses, and simple prisms, for the sake of clarity) is:

```
outside :: Prism' s a -> Lens' (s -> r) (a -> r)
```

Given a prism for e.g. a case of a sum type, `outside` gives you a lens on functions from the sum type which targets the branch of the function that handles the case. Specifying all branches of the function amounts to handling all cases:

```
problemName :: Problem -> String
problemName = error "Unhandled case in problemName"
    & outside _ProblemFoo .~ view fooName
    & outside _ProblemBar .~ view barName
    & outside _ProblemBaz .~ view bazName
```

That is rather pretty, except for the need to throw in the `error` case due to the lack of a sensible default. [The *total* library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/total-1.0.5/docs/Lens-Family-Total.html) offers an alternative that improves on that and provides exhaustiveness checking along the way, as long as you are willing to contort your types a bit further:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Control.Lens
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Lens.Family.Total    

-- etc.

-- This is needed for total's exhaustiveness check.
data Problem_ a b c =
    ProblemFoo a |
    ProblemBar b |
    ProblemBaz c
    deriving (Generic, Eq, Ord, Show)
makePrisms ''Problem_

instance (Empty a, Empty b, Empty c) => Empty (Problem_ a b c)

type Problem = Problem_ Foo Bar Baz

problemName :: Problem -> String
problemName = _case
    & on _ProblemFoo (view fooName)
    & on _ProblemBar (view barName)
    & on _ProblemBaz (view bazName)
```

Answer (score 6):

[The function you probably want](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:choosing) is

```
choosing :: Functor f => LensLike f s t a b -> LensLike f s' t' a b -> LensLike f (Either s s') (Either t t') a b
```

to be read as

```
choosing :: Lens' s   a      -> Lens' s'  a      -> Lens' (Either s s')    a
```

or in your case

```
choosing :: Lens' Foo String -> Lens' Bar String -> Lens' (Either Foo Bar) String
```

To use that with `Problem`, you'll need the fact that `Problem` is actually isomorphic to `Either Foo Bar`. Existance of both a `Prism' Problem Foo` and `Prism' Problem Bar` isn't sufficient for that, because you could also have

```
data Problem' = Problem'Foo Foo
              | Spoilsport
              | Problem'Bar Bar
```

I don't think there's any standard TH utility for giving such an isomorphism using more than one constructor, but you can write it yourself, which is somewhat easier than writing the lens onto the string yourself:

```
delegateProblem :: Iso' Problem (Either Foo Bar)
delegateProblem = iso p2e e2p
 where p2e (ProblemFoo foo) = Left foo
       p2e (ProblemBar bar) = Right bar
       e2p (Left foo) = ProblemFoo foo
       e2p (Right bar) = ProblemBar bar
```

and with that

```
problemName :: Lens' Problem String
problemName = delegateProblem . choosing fooName barName
```

Short version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
problemName = iso (\case ProblemFoo foo -> Left foo
                         ProblemBar bar -> Right bar)
                  (\case Left foo -> ProblemFoo foo
                         Right bar -> ProblemBar bar)
            . choosing fooName barName
```

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately my actual data type has 5 variants, not just 2. They all have the necessary lens though (see my edited version). However it might be possible to daisy-chain Eithers and `choosing`.

Comment: It turns out that writing the Iso is exactly as much code as writing the lens getter and setter functions; both need a forwards and backwards case for each constructor. So it looks like there isn't a clever way of doing this. If nobody comes up with anything else then I'll accept this as the best available answer.

Comment: What's TBRA? Google comes up empty.

Comment: @WillNess TBRA is to be read as _to be read as_. Hm, IMO that should be established ASAP. YMMV. _Anyway,.._

Comment: ____chuckle____. :)

Answer (score 6):

Sure, it's very mechanical:

```
problemName :: Lens' Problem String
problemName f = \case
    ProblemFoo foo -> ProblemFoo <$> fooName f foo
    ProblemBar bar -> ProblemBar <$> barName f bar
    ProblemBaz baz -> ProblemBaz <$> bazName f baz
```

It should be obvious how to extend this to further constructors, or even how to write a bit of TH for it provided you can think of a way to describe the right sub-lens to pick for each branch -- perhaps using a typeclass for dispatch or similar.

Comment: Ahh, right. I've done it using the `lens` combinator with separate `goForwards` and `goBackwards` functions, making two cases for each constructor. But this does it with only one. Definitely neater, and probably the simplest possible solution.